# Customize toast in asyntask in android

Tags: android-asynctask, toast

I just wanna ask if it is possible to use my customize toast in onPostExecute of my Asyntask in android. If yes then how? I tried to put it on the onPostExecute but I got a lot red lines. Here is my code for my customize toast:

```
Typeface tfR= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Gothic_Regular.TTF");
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_bg, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.toastAttribute));
    TextView msg = ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.txt_toast));
    msg.setTypeface(tfR);
    msg.setText(toast_msg);
    msg.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,16);
    Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
    mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
    mytoast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    mytoast.show();
```

Then I want to put it here:

```
public class DoPost extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> 
{
    Exception exception = null;
    Context mContext = null;

        . . . . . 


public DoPost(Context context, String username, String password,
        String reportcode, String remarks, String date, String province,
        String infotype, String competitor, ArrayList<String> brands,
        ArrayList<String> segments) 
{
    mContext         = context;

           . . . .

    databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    if (databaseHandler != null)
    {
        databaseHandler.close();
        databaseHandler.createDB();
    }
}

protected void onPreExecute() 
{
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading attachment details....");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) 
{

    try {
            JSONObject jObject              = new JSONObject();

            Log.d("DoPost Constants.FILE_URI", Constants.FILE_URI.toString());
            Log.d("DoPost create SELECTEDFILE URI", SelectedFiles.listFileUri.toString());
            Log.d("DoPost create SELECTEDFILE FILENAME", SelectedFiles.listFileName.toString());

        //  String filename                 = "Chapt-19.pdf";
            String filename                 = "";
            try {

                JSONArray jArraySubrands            = new JSONArray();
                JSONArray jArrayConsumerSegments    = new JSONArray();
                JSONArray jArrayReportUpload    = new JSONArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_SUBBRANDS.size(); i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject brand = new JSONObject();
                    brand.put("Id", _brands.get(i));
                    jArraySubrands.put(brand);
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_SEGMENTS.size(); j++) 
                {
                    JSONObject consumerSegments = new JSONObject();
                    consumerSegments.put("Id", _segments.get(j));
                    jArrayConsumerSegments.put(consumerSegments);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < Constants.ARRAYLIST_FILENAME.size(); i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject jObjectReportUpload  = new JSONObject();
                    filename = Constants.ARRAYLIST_FILENAME.get(i);
                    jObjectReportUpload.put("ReportUploadId", 0);
                    jObjectReportUpload.put("Filename", filename);
                    jObjectReportUpload.put("TempFilename", filename);
                    jObjectReportUpload.put("Description", "Image Testing");
                    jObjectReportUpload.put("ReportUploadTypeId", 1);
                    jObjectReportUpload.put("ReportId", 0);
                    jArrayReportUpload.put(jObjectReportUpload);

                    Log.d("filename: ", filename);

                }

                jObject.put("ReportId", 0);
                jObject.put("ReportCode", _code);
                jObject.put("Title", "Mobile Developer");
                jObject.put("Remarks", _remarks);
                jObject.put("DateObserved", _date);
                jObject.put("ProvinceId", _province);
                jObject.put("InformationTypeId", _infotype);
                jObject.put("ReportTypeId", 1);
                jObject.put("IsCompetitor", _competitor);
                jObject.put("SubBrands", jArraySubrands);
                jObject.put("ConsumerSegments", jArrayConsumerSegments);
                jObject.put("ReportUploads", jArrayReportUpload);

            } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ResponseHandler<String> resonseHandler  = new BasicResponseHandler();
            HttpParams httpParameters               = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
            HttpPost httpPost                       = new HttpPost("http://phsjghhghghulchghg4.hgh.com:1214/api/reports");
            HttpClient httpclient                   = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            httpPost.addHeader("Authorization","Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString((_username + ":" + _password).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(jObject.toString().getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8)));

            String response = httpclient.execute(httpPost).toString();
            Log.i("response: ", response);
            Log.i("JSON", jObject.toString());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Header","ClientProtocolException in callWebService(). "+ e.getMessage());
                error = String.valueOf(e);
                return false;
            } 
    catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Header","IOException in callWebService(). " + e.getMessage());
            error = String.valueOf(e);
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean valid) 
{
    progressDialog.dismiss();

    Log.d("RESULT", String.valueOf(valid));

    if(valid){
        //Customzize toast here.
        new DoPost(mContext,_username, _password, _code, _remarks, _date, _province, _infotype,_competitor,_brands, _segments).execute();

    }else{
        //Customzize toast here.

    }
}
```

Comment: a lot red lines? error logs?

Comment: redlines because the getAssets, getLayoutInflater, findViewById, getBaseContext is not working on my asyntask class and it asking to create a method like that

Comment: how did you initialize your mContext?

Comment: could you post full code of your custom AysncTask and Toast?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found out what's going on. Your scope is wrong. currently your code is running in AsyncTask, not Activity! That's why you cannot use getAssets, getLayoutInflater, findViewById, getBaseContext. Create your AsyncTask in your xxxActivity. And use Your xxxActivity.this.findViewById, and so on.

Comment: try 'LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();' or 'LayoutInflater inflater = xxxActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();'